# How to apply CSS class to a parent element?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following bootstrap pills on `page1.htm`:

```
<div>
   <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" >
    <li role="presentation" class=""><a href="someurl.htm#apply" class="js-apply">Apply</a></li>
    <li role="presentation" class=""><a href="someurl.html#report" class="js-report">Report</a></li>
    <li role="presentation" class=""><a href="someurl.html#book" class="js-book">Book</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

on `page2.htm` I have the following link

```
<a class="btn btn-default" href="page1.htm#apply" role="button">Apply</a>
```

When I click the above link to go to `page1.htm`, how do I extract the anchor id attribute from the url to set list item on `page1.htm` with the same anchor id attribute to active i.e. the following list tag should become active:

```
<li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="someurl.htm#apply" >Apply</a></li>
```

Similarly if I click the following link, I want to set the list item on `page1.htm` with the same anchor id attribute to active.

```
<a class="btn btn-default" href="page1.htm#report" role="button">Apply</a>
```

I use the following to get the hash:

```
var url = document.location.toString(), idx = url.indexOf("#")
var hash = idx != -1 ? url.substring(idx+1) : "";
```

Comment: Could you include the code do you currently have / tell us where the problem is, specifically?

Comment: You could check the current URL and if the URL matches one of the links in the nav then set the class to active.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `window.location.hash` to get the ID from the URL. From there loop through the anchors of your unordered list checking the `href` value for the hash.

This example uses jQuery.

```js
var hash = window.location.hash

$( '.nav-pills a' ).each( function( i, e ) {

    var $a = $( this );

    if ( hash && -1 !== $a.attr( 'href' ).indexOf( hash ) ) {
        $a.parent().addClass( 'active' ); // add class to <li>
    }

} );
```

Here is a jsFiddle demonstrating the code: http://jsfiddle.net/6dyee7b0/15/

### Example Code

#### HTML

```html
<ul class="nav-pills">
    <li><a href="some-url.html#one">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="some-url.html#two">Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="some-url.html#three">Three</a></li>
    <li><a href="some-url.html#four">Four</a></li>
    <li><a href="some-url.html#five">Five</a></li>
    <li><a href="some-url.html#six">Six</a></li>
</ul>
```

#### CSS

```css
.active a {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: This is an elegant solution. Thanks.

Comment: updated code to add class to <li> element: `$(this).closest('li').addClass( 'active' );`

Comment: I'm sorry, I missed that part. I've updated my answer. Please note that it uses `parent()` instead of `closest()`. Also updated jsFiddle.

Comment: If there is no hash all the links end up getting the active class applied. How do you make it so that if there is no hash then the active class doesnt need to get applied?

Comment: Nice catch @ozzii, updated answer again. You simply check for a [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value for `hash` first, which an empty string is [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy). Then if you have something to work with it can move onto the next check in the statement that finds out if that value is in the `href`.

Answer (score 2):

Use js to check the url for a hash, then use that to apply a class to li

```
if (window.location.hash == "#apply") {
    $("ul.nav-pills li:first-child").addClass("active");
}
if (window.location.hash == "#report") {
    $("ul.nav-pills li:last-child").addClass("active");
}
```

Comment: what if I have multiple list items, do i have to check every child e.g `$("ul.nav-pills li:second-child").addClass("active");`

Answer (score 0):

Since your hashes conveniently match your classes, you can just use the one directly in the other:

```
var wh = window.location.hash.substr(1); // .substr(1) removes the '#'
if (wh === 'apply' || wh === 'report' || wh === 'book') {
    $('ul.nav-pills li.'+wh).addClass('active');
}
```

You could probably safely skip the validation step, since worst case you'd add `.active` to a nonexistent element, but explicit is usually better...